How to access and look inside our app sandbox folder when we are coding our app?
I need to look inside my app sandbox while I am developing my app, for example seeing created data file or removing old bookmarks and some works like that, is there an option or button in Xcode for showing the sandbox of our app in macOS apps or iOS apps?

I would just print URL.documentsDirectory and go there with Finder. Did I understand your question correctly?

Yes, I just want to look for folder in Finder, but is there an easy way like a click or an app to buy?

I don't think there is a button... But perhaps you can open it from the terminal, using xcrun simctl or something like that.

I don't know about buttons, but there is a command to do that:
open $(xcrun simctl get_app_container 'iPhone 15 Pro Max' io.github.sweeper777.Foo data)

Replace iPhone 15 Pro Max with the name of the simulator, and replace io.github.sweeper777.Foo with the bundle identifier of your app.
For macOS, the location is fixed, so you can just pass the direct path to the open command
open ~/Library/Containers/io.github.sweeper777.Foo/Data

Again, replace io.github.sweeper777.Foo with the bundle ID.

Yes, what about macOS apps?

@swiftPunk That's simpler. See the edit.

Yes, can you make a command for macOS as well? because in macOS I have to use Go to Folder...

@swiftPunk You can simply use the open command to open a folder in finder.
